# Why is sudoedit writing to a temporary directory?

Tags: sudoedit

I used `sudoedit` to create a file:

```
 $ sudoedit /etc/systemd/system/apache2.service
```

but when I went to save the file, it wrote it in a temporary directory (/var/temp/blahblah). What is going on? Why is it not saving it to the system directory?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The point of `sudoedit` is to allow users to edit files they wouldn’t otherwise be allowed to, while running an unprivileged editor. To make this happen, `sudoedit` copies the file to be edited to a temporary location, makes it writable by the requesting user, and opens it in the configured editor. That’s why the editor shows an unrelated filename in a temporary directory. When the editor exits, `sudoedit` checks whether any changes were really made, and copies the changed temporary file back to its original location if necessary.

Comment: IIRC some editors will also do basic sanity checks to ensure that no computer-bricking changes were made, but I'm not sure how common that is,.

Comment: @NicHartley: It's hard to do that in the general case, because there are so many varied ways to brick your computer.  It tends to be application specific, e.g. with `visudo` for `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: @Kevin Oh, whoops, I think I confused `visudo` for `sudoedit`. I knew `visudo` did it for sure. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 2):

This is nicely explained in [the `sudo` manpage](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.3/sudo.man.html). The description of `-e` (which `sudoedit` is equivalent to) says:

> `-e`
>
> The `-e` (edit) option indicates that, instead of running a command, the user wishes to edit one or more files. In lieu of a command, the string "`sudoedit`" is used when consulting the security policy. If the user is authorized by the policy, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Temporary copies are made of the files to be edited with the owner set to the invoking user.
> 2. The editor specified by the policy is run to edit the temporary files. The `sudoers` policy uses the `SUDO_EDITOR`, `VISUAL` and `EDITOR` environment variables (in that order). If none of `SUDO_EDITOR`, `VISUAL` or `EDITOR` are set, the first program listed in the editor `sudoers(5)` option is used.
> 3. If they have been modified, the temporary files are copied back to their original location and the temporary versions are removed.
>
> If the specified file does not exist, it will be created. Note that unlike most commands run by `sudo`, the editor is run with the invoking user's environment unmodified. If, for some reason, `sudo` is unable to update a file with its edited version, the user will receive a warning and the edited copy will remain in a temporary file.

In particular, note the third step: only if the file has been modified at the end of editing is the original changed. So, if you have a program that watches a file, this can help avoid (a) intermediate writes being picked up, and (b)  unnecessary actions if you decided to make no changes in the end.